como traer un dato de un modelo en un form de otro modelo
soy un poco nueva en la programación con django y necesito ayuda ya que en la carga de un formulario uno de los campos (telefono)lo tengo buscar de otra tabla y mostrar en el proceso de ingreso de los datos. Es posible hacer eso?
Forms
class formularionuevo (forms.Form):
    uso=forms.ChoiceField(label="Uso del equipamiento(*) ",choices=USO, widget=forms.widgets.RadioSelect(), initial='INTERNO')
    fecha_retiro=forms.DateField(label="Fecha retiro(*) ",widget=NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}), initial = datetime.date.today())
    hora_retiro=forms.TimeField(label="Hora retiro(*) ",widget = NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}), help_text= "HH:MM",required=True)
    fecha_devolucion=forms.DateField(label="Fecha devolución(*)",widget=NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}), initial = datetime.date.today())
    hora_devolucion=forms.TimeField(label="Hora devolución(*)",widget = NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}))
    periodo=forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'custom-class'}), label='Reserva completa entre fechas(*)')
    dia_semana=forms.MultipleChoiceField(label="Día de la semana(*) ",choices=DIA_SEMANA, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'style': 'display: inline-block'}),required=False)
    responsable=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Personas.objects.all().order_by('apellido','nombre'), label="Responsable(*)")
    telefono=forms.CharField(label="Telefono(*)")
    finalidad=forms.CharField(label="Finalidad", required=False)
    area_pedido=forms.ChoiceField(choices=AREA_PEDIDO, label="Área del pedido(*)")
    operador=forms.ChoiceField(label="Entregado por(*) ",choices=OPERADOR)
    lugardeuso=forms.CharField(label="Lugar de uso(*)")
    observacion=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':3}), label="Observaciones ", required=False)
    autoriz_adm=forms.CharField(label= "Seleccione Archivo con la autorización adm.  ", widget= forms.FileInput( ) ,required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Remito
        fields = ['uso', 'fecha_retiro', 'hora_retiro', 'periodo',
                'fecha_devolucion', 'hora_devolucion', 'dia_semana','autoriz_adm','telefono','finalidad', 'responsable',
                'area_pedido', 'operador', 'lugardeuso', 'observacion','autoriz_adm']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        hora_actual = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M')
        fecha_actual =datetime.date.today()
        self.fields['hora_retiro'].initial = hora_actual
        self.fields['fecha_retiro'].initial = fecha_actual 
        self.fields['fecha_devolucion'].initial = fecha_actual 
        self.fields['finalidad'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'width: 300px;'

Models
class Personas (models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Nombre (*)')
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Apellido (*)')
    dni = models.IntegerField (blank=True, null=True)
    email= models.EmailField(blank= True, null=True)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=40,blank=True, default='')
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='')
    profesion = models.CharField(max_length=45,blank=True, default='')
    observacion = models.TextField(blank= True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0},{1}'.format(self.apellido, self.nombre)

    
class Remito (models.Model):
    uso= models.CharField(choices=USO, max_length=50, default='INTERNO')
    fecha_retiro = models.DateField(blank=True )
    hora_retiro = models.TimeField(null=True, blank= True)
    periodo= models.BooleanField(default= False)
    dia_semana = MultiSelectField(choices=DIA_SEMANA, max_length=10) 
    fecha_devolucion = models.DateField(blank=True )
    hora_devolucion = models.TimeField(null=True, blank= True)
    responsable =  models.ForeignKey(Personas, null=True, blank= True, verbose_name='Responsable',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    persona_retira=models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank= True, verbose_name='Persona que retira')
    telefono=models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank= True, verbose_name='Telefono')
    area_pedido =  models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=AREA_PEDIDO, verbose_name='Área del pedido')
    operador =  models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=OPERADOR, verbose_name='Entregado por')
    lugardeuso =  models.CharField(max_length=40,verbose_name='Lugar uso')
    finalidad = models.CharField(null=True, blank= True,max_length=40,verbose_name='Finalidad')
    observacion =  models.TextField(blank= True, null=True)
    estado= models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=ESTADOS, default='Pendiente',verbose_name='Estado del remito')
    autoriz_adm = models.FileField(blank= True, null=True, upload_to='remitos/')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'N°: %d' % (self.id)

Telefono de persona debe ser guardado en telefono de Remito en el porceso de carga de un remito.
Views
def nuevo (request):
    recur= Recursos.objects.all()
    form = formularionuevo()
    user = request.user
    url_domain = get_current_site(request).domain
    context = {
                'form': form,
                'user': user,
                'url_domain': url_domain,
                'recur': recur,
                }
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=formularionuevo(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            remito=Remito()
            remito.uso=form.cleaned_data['uso']
            
           # remito.autoriz_adm =request.FILES['autoriz_adm']
            if remito.uso=="EXTERNO":
                remito.autoriz_adm = request.FILES.get('autoriz_adm')
            else:
                remito.autoriz_adm = None
            
            if remito.uso == "EXTERNO" and remito.autoriz_adm == None:
                messages.success(request, "ERROR- Si el uso del remito es EXTERNO necesita autorización de Administración")
                form=formularionuevo(data=request.POST)
                return render(request, "RemitoTicapp/nuevo.html", context)
            
            retiro=form.cleaned_data['fecha_retiro']
            devolucion=form.cleaned_data['fecha_devolucion']
            remito.periodo=form.cleaned_data['periodo']
            dia_semana=form.cleaned_data['dia_semana'] 
            
            ....  
            remito.dia_semana=form.cleaned_data['dia_semana']   
            remito.hora_retiro=form.cleaned_data['hora_retiro']
            remito.hora_devolucion=form.cleaned_data['hora_devolucion']
            remito.responsable=form.cleaned_data['responsable']
            remito.finalidad=form.cleaned_data['finalidad']
            remito.telefono=form.cleaned_data['telefono']
            remito.area_pedido=form.cleaned_data['area_pedido']
            remito.operador=form.cleaned_data['operador']
            remito.lugardeuso=form.cleaned_data['lugardeuso']
            remito.observacion=form.cleaned_data['observacion']
            remito.estado='Pendiente'
            remito.save()  
            return HttpResponseRedirect('addrecurso/%d/'%remito.id)
            
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            form=formularionuevo(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
            messages.success(request, "ERROR- Revise los datos (hora devolución o dia de la semana)")
            
             
    return render(request, "RemitoTicapp/nuevo.html", context)


y en la parte del html tengo solo los campos  y adicione un botón para ingresar una nueva persona. necesito que en el lugar donde tome el telefono me aparezca el dato del telefono guardado en la tabla persona.
 <hr>
                     <label> {{ form.responsable.label }} {{ form.responsable.help_text }}:   </label> 
                    {{ form.responsable }} 
                    <a href="{% url 'nueva_persona'  %}" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <img src="{% static 'RemitoTicapp/img/addcontact.png' %}" width="15px" alt="Dibujo de adición"> 
                     </a>
                    <br/> 
                    <label> {{ form.telefono.label }} {{ form.telefono.help_text }}:   </label>
                    {{ form.telefono}}<br/> 
                     <br/>  


